# Chart.js data not initially loaded

Tags: javascript, reactjs, chart.js

I'm using *Chart.js* to display two graphs using data that is unique to each user. These graphs are working correctly but only once the page is reloaded by clicking on the home icon within the site. When the page is initially loaded there is no data for the graphs to use when they are rendered.
Is there a way to get around this so the graphs have the data when they are initially rendered?

`getVals` is used to create the data needed for the graphs.

```
import React, { Fragment, useEffect, useState } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { deleteAccount, getCurrentProfile } from "../../actions/profile";
import Spinner from "../layout/Spinner";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import Experience from "./Experience";
import Education from "./Education";
import ProjectForm from "../project/ProjectForm";
import DashboardActions from "./DashboardActions";
import projectItem from "../project/projectItem";
import { getProjects } from "../../actions/project";
import { deleteProject } from "../../actions/project";
import Moment from "react-moment";
import { Line } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Doughnut } from "react-chartjs-2";
import { Bar } from "react-chartjs-2";

const Dashboard = ({
  deleteProject,
  auth,
  getCurrentProfile,
  deleteAccount,
  getProjects,
  auth: { user },
  profile: { profile, loading },
  project: { projects, name, avatar },
}) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();

    getCurrentProfile();

    chart();
    barChart();
  }, [getCurrentProfile]);

  const [chartData, setChartData] = useState({});

  const [barChartData, setBarChartData] = useState({});

  var low = 0;
  var medium = 0;
  var high = 0;
  var urgent = 0;
  var total = 0;
  var projectNames = [];
  var barData = [];



  const getVals = () => {
    projects.length === 0
      ? getProjects()
      : projects.map((project) =>
          project.user === user._id
            ? (barData.push(project.tickets.length),
              projectNames.push(project.projectName),
              project.tickets.map(
                (ticket) => (
                  console.log(ticket.priority),
                  (total = total + 1),
                  ticket.priority == "Low" ? (low = low + 1) : null,
                  ticket.priority == "Medium" ? (medium = medium + 1) : null,
                  ticket.priority == "High" ? (high = high + 1) : null,
                  ticket.priority == "Urgent" ? (urgent = urgent + 1) : null
                )
              ))
            : //else if the current user is a member add the project to the graphs
              project.members.map((member) =>
                member.id == user._id
                  ? project.user !== member.id
                    ? projectNames.push(project.projectName) &&
                      barData.push(project.tickets.length)
                    : null
                  : null
              )
        );
  };

  const chart = () => {
    setChartData({
      labels: ["low", "medium", "high", "urgent"],

      datasets: [
        {
          label: "label",
          data: [low, medium, high, urgent],
          backgroundColor: ["#0a6ef0", "#0af021", "#fc8c03", "#fc0303"],
          borderWidth: 4,
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  const barChart = () => {
    setBarChartData({
      labels: projectNames,

      datasets: [
        {
          label: "label",
          data: barData,
          backgroundColor: ["#0a6ef0", "#0af021", "#fc8c03", "#fc0303"],
          borderWidth: 4,
        },
      ],
    });
  };

  return loading && profile === null ? (
    <Spinner />
  ) : (
    <Fragment className="pageWrapper">
      <div className="pageWrapperMarginForNav">
        {/* //chnage to just projects this user it part of */}

        <div className="dashHeading">
          <h1 className="largeDash text-primary">Dashboard</h1>
          <p className="lead">
            <i className="fas fa-user" /> Welcome {user && user.name}
          </p>
        </div>

        {profile != null ? (
          <Fragment>
       

            <div className="graphs">
              <div className="graph">
                {getVals()}
                {total === 0 ? (
                  <h1>Looks Like you havent started any projects yet</h1>
                ) : (
                  <Doughnut
                    data={chartData}
                    options={{
                      responsive: true,
                      title: { text: "Proportion Of Tickets", display: true },
                      scales: {
                        yAxes: [],
                      },
                    }}
                  />
                )}
              </div>

              <div className="barGraph">
                <Bar
                  data={barChartData}
                  options={{
                    title: { text: "Tickets Per Project", display: true },

                    scales: {
                      xAxes: [
                        {
                          barPercentage: 0.6,
                        },
                      ],
                    },
                  }}
                />
              </div>
            </div>
          </Fragment>
        ) : (
          <Fragment>
            <p>You have not yet setup a profile, please add some info</p>
            <Link to="/create-profile" className="btn btn-primary my-1">
              Create Profile
            </Link>
          </Fragment>
        )}
      </div>
    </Fragment>
  );
};

Dashboard.propTypes = {
  getCurrentProfile: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  auth: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  profile: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  deleteAccount: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  deleteProject: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
};

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  auth: state.auth,
  profile: state.profile,
  project: state.project,
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, {
  getCurrentProfile,
  deleteAccount,
  getProjects,
  deleteProject,
})(Dashboard);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();

    getCurrentProfile();

    chart();
    barChart();
  }, [getCurrentProfile]);
```

Note the above useEffect does not get called when page is loaded. May want to change to

```
 useEffect(() => {
    getProjects();

    getCurrentProfile();

    chart();
    barChart();
  }, []);
```

Comment: Thank you for the advice, although this does not fix the Chart.js issue.

Comment: Does your chart need to wait for getCurrentProfile to complete? Does it depend on  `profile: { profile, loading }`? If yes, set the dependency to e.g. [profile, loading]